# How to cover a number of points with disks?

Tags: qgis

I have to cover some points with disks. These disks are not of a fixed size, they have to constraints:

- a maximum diameter, and
- a maximum number of points covered.

I would like to minimize/optimize the number of disks centers.

- A point can be covered by two disks, but counts for only one of them.
- All points should be covered.

The maximum number of points would be approx 40 per disk, and points are houses: a distribution based on pockets, lines (along roads) and isolated. It is for a whole country, so approx a million of points.

Comment: Can you update your question and add a visual or screen shot?

Comment: what is your maximum number of points?

Comment: Hi, I don't have the input data yet. However the maximum number of points would be approx 40, and points could be houses: a distribution based on pockets, lines (along roads) and isolated.

Comment: I'd see if you could break this problem down a little before addressing it. Do the centre of these disks have fixed locations, or are they essentially random? One way you could approach this is to construct a grid in the first instance (using the QGIS sampling grid tool) with fixed size cells and then use this to run a frequency count on the number of points in each cell. You could do this several times for different cell sizes until you got the cluster membership thresholds you desire. Then you would select all the populated cells. This would cut down the geography your disks need to cover.

Comment: Next you could convert the grid to points - giving the four points that define the extent of each of the cells. You could use this as the basis for buffering to generate the optimum for the discs. It would be iterative and messy - that's why this isn't an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jean,
       I will add this as an answer because I am not allowed to comment yet.

What you describe is a form of the capacitated clustering problem, which is a traditional problem in Operations Research. Reading that literature will probably help you.  This paper gives you a good idea:  http://sblocal.aub.edu.lb/personalsites/drosman/docs/Articles%20-%20pdf/hsats-ccp.pdf

I will also say that this is probably better done outside a GIS environment.  I once programmed it in VBA for Excel (about a decade ago), but I bet you can find modern implementations of that in better languages.  This paper gives you a good idea of a possible algorithm: http://www.dcc.ufla.br/infocomp/artigos/v8.4/art07.pdf

Comment: +1 for the reference to capacity clustering. I'm sure anything that can be done in VB for Excel can be done just as well with Python in a GIS environment.

Comment: It can totally be done in a GIS environment, @underdark . What I meant is that the algorithm is not in the realm of GIS, but rather in the operations research one. It would be really nice to see some of those algorithms (P-Medians, clustering, etc) added to a plugin (maybe my next work?)